# RowCommand VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, gridview

Estou com o seguinte problema ao deletar uma linha do `asp:gridview`.

Quando eu deixo o **código**(chave) `visible="false"` no `gridview`, o valor retornado na minha variável *chaveDelete* vem *empty*. Mas quando eu deixo `visible="true"` a função pega o valor correto, alguém sabe de uma solução pra pegar o valor mesmo com o `visible="false"` da minha chave?

```
Protected Sub gvLivros_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs) Handles gvLivros.RowCommand
    Dim objLivros As New ClasseLivros

    If e.CommandName = "Excluir" Then
        Dim index As Integer = Integer.Parse(DirectCast(e.CommandArgument, String))
        Dim chaveDelete = gvLivros.Rows(index).Cells(0).Text

        objLivros.ExcluirLivro(Convert.ToInt32(chaveDelete))
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente cara, vlw!!!

Comment: Fico feliz em ter ajudado :). Se possível marque a reposta como aceita.

Answer (score 1):

Uma das [maneiras](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/80964/How-to-get-Hidden-Column-Value-in-GridView) de fazer isto é usar a propriedade [`DataKeyNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames(v=vs.110).aspx) do `GridView`. Para usá-la, basta especificar o nome da(s) coluna(s) em `DataKeyNames`.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvLivros" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="Chave, Secao" OnRowCommand="gvLivros_RowCommand">
<Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Livro" HeaderText="Livro" ItemStyle-Width="150" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Preco" HeaderText="Preço" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
    <asp:ButtonField CommandName="Comprar" Text="Comprar" ButtonType="Button" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Populando o `GridView`:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(3) {New DataColumn("Chave"), New DataColumn("Secao"), New DataColumn("Livro"), New DataColumn("Preco")})
        dt.Rows.Add(1, "A", "Foo", "5")
        dt.Rows.Add(2, "B", "Bar", "10")
        dt.Rows.Add(3, "A", "Baz", "15")
        dt.Rows.Add(4, "B", "Poo", "20")
        GridView1.DataSource = dt
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

Evento `RowCommand`:

```
Protected Sub gvLivros_RowCommand(sender As Object, e As GridViewCommandEventArgs)
    Dim index As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)

    ' Obter o valor das colunas a partir de DataKeys usando como índice a variável index.
    Dim chave As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(gvLivros.DataKeys(index).Values(0))
    Dim secao As String = gvLivros.DataKeys(index).Values(1).ToString()
End Sub
```

Referência:

- [Get value of DataKeyNames (DataKeys) in RowCommand and RowDataBound events of ASP.Net GridView](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Get-value-of-DataKeyNames-DataKeys-in-RowCommand-and-RowDataBound-events-of-ASPNet-GridView.aspx)